# How do I use a stored payment source for a purchase in ActiveMerchant?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, payment-gateway, activemerchant, braintree

I'm using ActiveMerchant with Braintree as my payment processor. I want to take advantage of Braintree's customer vault functionality to store credit card info.

Storage goes fine, but I can't figure out the correct way to charge the credit card with the `customer_vault_id`. It seems very straight-forward according to the [Braintree documentation](http://dev.braintreepaymentsolutions.com/vault/direct-post#issuingtransaction), but I'm not sure how to pass this through ActiveMerchant. I get validation errors from Braintree if I send a credit card with empty data, and errors from ActiveMerchant if I try `nil`. The only thing that seems obvious is to send the `customer_vault_id` in the `purchase_options` hash, like:

```
GATEWAY.purchase(self.price_in_cents, self.credit_card, 
                 :ip => self.ip_address,
                 :customer_vault_id => 12345)
```

Is this the correct way to use a stored customer vault?

If so, what is the correct second argument for this line if I want to use a stored customer vault as payment method?

Thanks.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I discovered that you can substitute the `customer_vault_id` as a string for the `ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard` in the purchase method. The docs really don't have any indication of this :(

Answer (score 1):

After you call #store on the gateway, you will get a response, which you need to store the authorization.

Per the docs found in the wiki: https://github.com/activemerchant/active_merchant/wiki/Patterns-&-Standards

**store**
It's critical that store returns a token that can be used against purchase and authorize. Currently the standard is to return the token in the Response#authorization field.

**payment method**
String/token: Representation of a payment method tokenized via store

e.g.

```
gateway = ActiveMerchant::Billing::BraintreeGateway.new(login: login, password: password)
credit_card = ActiveMerchant::Billing::CreditCard.new(
                :first_name         => 'Bob',
                :last_name          => 'Bobsen',
                :number             => '4242424242424242',
                :month              => '8',
                :year               => Time.now.year+1,
                :verification_value => '000')
response = gateway.store(credit_card)
=> #<ActiveMerchant::Billing::Response:0x00007f8efb3df1a8
 @authorization="1508682289#1508160804#cim_store",
 @avs_result={"code"=>nil, "message"=>nil, "street_match"=>nil, "postal_match"=>nil},
 @cvv_result={"code"=>nil, "message"=>nil},
 @emv_authorization=nil,
 @error_code=nil,
 @fraud_review=false,
 @message="Successful",
 @params=
  {"message_code"=>"1",
   "message_text"=>"Successful",
   "result_code"=>"Ok",
   "test_request"=>nil,
   "customer_profile_id"=>"1508682289",
   "customer_payment_profile_id"=>"1508160804",
   "direct_response"=>nil},
 @success=true,
 @test=true>

response.authorization
=> "1508682289#1508160804#cim_store"
gateway.purchase(100, response.authorization)
=> #<ActiveMerchant::Billing::Response:0x00007f8ede0027c8
 @authorization="40036062888#XXXX4242#cim_purchase",
 @avs_result=
  {"code"=>"Y", "message"=>"Street address and 5-digit postal code match.", "street_match"=>"Y", "postal_match"=>"Y"},
 @cvv_result={"code"=>"P", "message"=>"CVV not processed"},
 @emv_authorization=nil,
 @error_code=nil,
 @fraud_review=false,
 @message="This transaction has been approved.",
 @params=
  {"message_code"=>"1",
   "message_text"=>"Successful",
   "result_code"=>"Ok",
   "test_request"=>nil,
   "customer_profile_id"=>nil,
   "customer_payment_profile_id"=>nil,
   "direct_response"=>
    "1,1,1,This transaction has been approved.,T91GL2,Y,40036062888,,,1.00,CC,auth_capture,2852040810cf440a4a13,Bob,Bobsen,,,,n&#47;a,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,P,2,,,,,,,,,,,XXXX4242,Visa,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,,",
   "response_code"=>1,
   "response_subcode"=>"1",
   "response_reason_code"=>"1",
   "response_reason_text"=>"This transaction has been approved.",
   "approval_code"=>"T91GL2",
   "avs_result_code"=>"Y",
   "transaction_id"=>"40036062888",
   "invoice_number"=>"",
   "order_description"=>"",
   "amount"=>"1.00",
   "method"=>"CC",
   "transaction_type"=>"auth_capture",
   "customer_id"=>"2852040810cf440a4a13",
   "first_name"=>"Bob",
   "last_name"=>"Bobsen",
   "company"=>"",
   "address"=>"",
   "city"=>"",
   "state"=>"n&#47;a",
   "zip_code"=>"",
   "country"=>"",
   "phone"=>"",
   "fax"=>"",
   "email_address"=>"",
   "ship_to_first_name"=>"",
   "ship_to_last_name"=>"",
   "ship_to_company"=>"",
   "ship_to_address"=>"",
   "ship_to_city"=>"",
   "ship_to_state"=>"",
   "ship_to_zip_code"=>"",
   "ship_to_country"=>"",
   "tax"=>"",
   "duty"=>"",
   "freight"=>"",
   "tax_exempt"=>"",
   "purchase_order_number"=>"",
   "md5_hash"=>"",
   "card_code"=>"P",
   "cardholder_authentication_verification_response"=>"2",
   "account_number"=>"XXXX4242",
   "card_type"=>"Visa",
   "split_tender_id"=>"",
   "requested_amount"=>"",
   "balance_on_card"=>""},
 @success=true,
 @test=true>
```